# How to reset OpenIdConnectConfiguration when IssuerSigningKeys changes?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, openid-connect

**Context:**

I have a .NET Core 3.1 app running on Azure web apps which uses Google authentication, `https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`. It is always alive and never restarts.

In the app `Startup.cs` I've got

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>("https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
                options.Configuration = configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
```

I also have

```cs
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKeys = options.Configuration.SigningKeys
                };
```

But every now and then, I get an exception

```
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
Exceptions caught:
 '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. 
token: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ValidateToken(String idToken, AuthenticationProperties properties, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, JwtSecurityToken& jwt)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

I think it's probably because Google has changed their keys. All I have to do to fix it is to restart the Azure Web app.

**My question is:**

Is there any way I can refresh the info from the .well-known when I catch the exception without restarting the app?

Comment: the `ConfigurationManager<T>` has some `RefreshInterval` you can set. are you seeing any interuption/error in your application or just logs ? I imagine if the jtw signing failed, it will automatically try to grab to the new config ?

Comment: Also i imagine google is publishing new public keys in advance so it shouldnt be an issue

Comment: @Thomas It is impossible to log in when it happens. I have to restart the app to be able to log in again.

Comment: You should always call `GetConfigurationAsync()`. It fetches last known configuration, and refreshes based on an interval. You should also catch signature verification exceptions and trigger a refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked [the same question](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/27067#discussioncomment-107061) in the github aspnetcore repository discussions.

[Tratcher](https://github.com/Tratcher) answered my question, pointing out a mistake I had made. I was resolving the actual configuration instead of passing the configurationmanager to the OpenIdConnectOptions:

Here's the fix:

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>("https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
                //options.Configuration = configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result; // remove this line
                options.ConfigurationManager = configurationManager; // add this line
```

```cs
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    // IssuerSigningKeys = options.Configuration.SigningKeys // remove this line
                };
```

EDIT: or even better, set `MetadataAddress` and a `ConfigurationManager` will be created automatically.

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["Google:WellKnown"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your API is receiving unrelated tokens some someone else that triggers the exception? Are you sure the exception is caused by your own requests?

Just to be sure if Google is rotating their keys when your app crashes, then I would save a copy locally of

https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

and then compare it with a new copy of that document when your app crashes and see why it fails. To see if the keys actually was changed by Google.

I would also temporary enable the PII logging

'[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
token: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

To see the details and the token details for further investigation.

Comment: Yes, because it is impossible to log in when it happens. I have to restart the app.

Comment: added some more thoughts to my answer.

Comment: More logging: Probably a good idea. I will do that, and wait for it to happen again.

Comment: I got the exact same error today at work, after a planned cert change on another app. I had planned for this so I scheduled a restart of the prod-version, but I can see the error in the test-version, which has not been restarted. The test-version is on "always running" and fails on each login because the certificate has changed. It will work again if I restart the app service.